# axios is not sending the session ID with the request from vue at localhost:5173 to backend at localhost:5000

Tags: node.js, vue.js, session, backend

I am trying to send an axios request from the vue front end to node js backend with sessionID to handle sessions for admins.

this is a login sample to login admins

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const submit = async (data) => {
  const { email, password } = data;
  const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/loginAdmin";

  try {
    const res = await axios.post(url, {
      email,
      password,
    });
    error.value = undefined;
    console.log(res.data);
    const loginIng = useLogin();
    loginIng.logIn(res.data);
    router.push("/");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    error.value = err.response.data.message;
  }
};
```

after the login is successfully done and that what happened with me, the user is pushed to the root at / and beforeMount the component, there a check to validate the admin credintials in the backend, like this

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
setup() {
const login = useLogin();
const router = useRouter();
onBeforeMount(() => {
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/validateAdmin")
    .then((res) => {
      login.logIn(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      router.push("/login");
    });
});
return {};
```

},

In the backend in the app.js, there is a session and cors policy to allow origin from the front end, and session is stored in sqlite3 like the following.

```
app.use(
  session({
    store: new KnexSessionStore({
      knex: db,
      tablename: "sessions",
    }),
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    },
  })
);
```

in the login admin the session is saving a user with his credintials
like this

```
const loginAdmin = async (req, res) => {
    req.session.user = admin;
}
```

and this is the ValidateAdmin endpoint sample

```
const validateAdmin = async (req, res) => {
  const userSession = req.session;
  const user = userSession.user;
}
```

the data is being saved to the sqlite3 file in the table, but each time the user visits the endpoint, there is a new id generated for him while i do not need that to happen

**What I have already tried:**
setting rolling: false, in the session
adding

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.session.touch();
  next();
});
```

to the app.js

Thanks in advance

Comment: cors issue? port is relevant.

Comment: it is not a cors issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after one month of trying to understand the issue. The problem was in the Vue cli version, which had some issues and prevented me from sending these requests. it was resolved by just using the latest version of the cli! I am posting the answer now as I just remembered that issue!